# Python 3.8.5 and socket with multicast gives [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied when with Python 3.8.3 worked OK

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.8

I'm doing a project with multicast in Python.
Up until now I was using Python 3.8.3 and it was working.
I changed to Python 3.8.5 and now I get  **[WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied** when configuring the port with the following code.

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.settimeout(6)
ttl = 2
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl)
bind_addr = '192.168.1.120'
try:
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, socket.inet_aton(bind_addr))
except socket.error as e:
    print("socket error", e)
```

Does someone know about changes on the socket library from Python 3.8.3 to Python 3.8.5 that may influence on why I'm getting this error?
Please do not tell me go back to Python 3.8.3, I know I can go back but this app will be run in other systems that I will not have control over which version of Python 3.8 they will use.

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this? I'm able to get the example to run using Python 3.8.10 and setting `bind_addr` to an address valid on my computer.

Comment: Hi TWReever, thanks for your help. 
This issue is no longer relevant.